# Converting Decimal to Hexadecimal and Octal

Tags: c, decimal, hex, octal

Show how to write a constant in C, whose decimal value is 65 as

a. a hexadecimal constant
`65/16 = 1 r1

1/16 = 0 r1

Hexadecimal constant = 11`
b. an octal constant (in C)
`65/8 = 8 r1

8/8 = 1 r0

1/8 = 0 r1
Octal constant = 101`

Is this the right way to convert constants in C?

Comment: 65/16 = 4 r1, so (ultimately) 65 decimal = 41 hexadecimal. Check your caluculations for the 65/8 also. This is not so much a `C` solution as simple arithmetic. You probably don't need to convert constants in  `C`, you just need to display them in different ways -- an *important* distinction.

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit confused. Are we supposed to be counting the remainders or how many times 16 goes into 65 when looking for hexadecimal constant? If it is the former, then would the octal constant be `65/8 = 8 r1` and `8/8 = 1 r0` = `80`? I guess I'm confused as to where to stop.

Comment: You need to keep track of both: how many times does 16 divide into 64 and what is the remainder? The problem of decimal 65 to octal should be more instructive.

Comment: It sounds to me like the question is asking how to write these constants in C, not how to compute them.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a while loop and a string. As this is homework, I do not think I should say more than that.

Answer (score 0):

The method is to divide by the base until the result is less than the base.

So 65/8 gives 8 r1  but you don't stop there because the result is 8 *not less than 8*

You divide by 8 again and get 1

It should be

65/64 = 10 r 1  where 64 = 8x8 = octal 10

I don't think I've said *too* much

Comment: Thanks, I thought that's what I had done originally in my question? From this table here, it says 65 decimal is 101 octal: http://www.ascii.cl/conversion.htm

Comment: Yes, if I'd added that it would have been giving you the answer to a homework question, and some SO users think that deserves a down vote even if your confusion is genuine. *By the way* don't forget to up-vote and accept the answer you think is most useful.;D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the questions, but it seems like you are being asked how hex and oct constants are represented in C, not how to implement an algorithm to convert dec to hex and oct.

If that is the case:

hex numbers are represented by a preceding 0x or 0X

oct numbers are represented by a preceding 0

```
int hex = 0x41;
int oct = 0101;
```

Of course, you can verify this by printing our the values in decimal:

```
printf("%d\n", hex);
printf("%d\n", oct);
```