# Howto encode/decode alphanumeric string to unsigned integer with defined set of chars

Tags: string, gcc

I have this charset  = [0123456789A BCDEFGH IJKLMNOPRTUVWZX]
I need to know howto convert any unsigned int to this in gcc/C

number - string
  02      = 2 
  10      = A
  20      = K
  30      = W
  1500    = ???
  8534    = ???

Comment: its like hexa encoding but with wide range characters and I dont know

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to convert decimal numbers to hexadecimal numbers, then you're essential there. To convert decimal to numbers in this character set, use the number of characters in the set as the base instead of 16.

If you don't know how to convert decimal to hexadecimal, a quick search will turn up the algorithm for you. Here's the first search result from this site:

[Converting Decimal to Hexadecimal and Octal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932235/converting-decimal-to-hexadecimal-and-octal)

Comment: this is not helping to me becouse here is 42 char set

Comment: Right, so 42 is your base. The most common algorithm for converting from decimal to another base involves repeated divisions using the base as the divisor. Do you know how to convert from decimal to hexadecimal?